# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'includes')

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am new to angular and was learning how to create custom directives. I was handling some email validations in email-validation.directive.ts and found that i am geting this error

**email-validation.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  ValidationErrors,
  Validator,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appEmailValidation]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: EmailValidationDirective,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class EmailValidationDirective implements Validator {
  count = 0;
  validate(control: AbstractControl<any, any>): ValidationErrors | null {
    const value = control.value as string;

    if (!value.includes('@') && !value.includes('.com')) {
      return {
        invalidEmail: true,
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
  constructor() {}
}
```

Here is my code and condition of my directive. I want to check if the email contains @ and .com keywords and if id doesn't I want to set invalidEmail as true
Main Component Code

**register.component.html**

```
<form #registerForm="ngForm" class="form-container" (ngSubmit)="postData(registerForm)">
  <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="100vh">
    <mat-grid-tile>
      <div class="example-container">
        <mat-form-field hintLabel="Max 20 characters" appearance="fill" class="width-50">
          <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
          <input #fname minlength="3" maxlength="20" required [(ngModel)]="ad.firstName" type="text" name="firstName"
            matInput placeholder="Enter Your Firstname">
          <mat-hint align="end">{{fname.value.length}}/20</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field hintLabel="Max 20 characters" appearance="fill" class="width-50 ml-2">
          <mat-label>Last name</mat-label>
          <input #lname minlength="3" maxlength="20" required [(ngModel)]="ad.lastName" name="lastName" type="text"
            matInput placeholder="Enter your Lastname">
          <mat-hint align="end">{{lname.value.length}}/20</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>
        <br>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-100">
          <mat-label>City</mat-label>
          <input minlength="3" maxlength="20" required [(ngModel)]="ad.city" name="city" type="text" matInput
            placeholder="Enter your City">
        </mat-form-field>
        <br>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-100">
          <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
          <input min="1" max="100" required [(ngModel)]="ad.age" name="age" type="number" matInput placeholder="Age">
        </mat-form-field>
        <br>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-100">
          <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
          <input appEmailValidation #user="ngModel" required [(ngModel)]="ad.username" name="username" matInput
            placeholder="Enter your username">
          <mat-hint color="warn"></mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>
        <br>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-100">
          <mat-label>Enter password</mat-label>
          <input required [(ngModel)]="ad.password" name="password" matInput [type]=" hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
          <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)=" hide=!hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
            [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
            <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button [disabled]="registerForm.invalid" mat-raised-button color="primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</form>
{{user.errors | json}}
```

When I am running the code i am getting this error
[Cannot read properties of null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S6N3.png)

Answer (score 1):

simply edit this condition:

```
if (!value || ( !value.includes('@') && !value.includes('.com'))) {
  return {
    invalidEmail: true,
  };
}
```

Because in your case `value` is `null` and I believe that `null` is also an invalid value for email.